# How can the formula of WD-40 remain a trade secret?

Tags: spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy, mass-spectrometry

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WD-40)

> WD-40's formula is a trade secret

How can it remain a secret today? Can't mass spectrometers, NMR and other equipment be used to determine the structure of the compounds that go into it?

To put the value of the secret into perspective, the WD-40 company (whose flagship product is its namesake) makes \$76M a year and is currently worth \$2.7B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"How can it remain secret?". Trivial answer is - it can't (it isn't).

WD40 is a Fast Moving Consumer Good (FMCG). It is also a reasonably cheap product - as an industrial chemist this suggests at least two things to me:

1. It doesn't contain anything rare or expensive
2. It isn't difficult to manufacture

As an ex-petroleum chemical analyst, with access to a reasonably complete lab, checks to do :

- Get the Safety Data Sheet (below is composite information from a number of WD-40 Penetrant SDS)

  cas        %
- 64742-47-8      50-70    isoparaffins petroleum hydrotreated HFP

  64742-56-9      30-35    paraffinic distillate, light, solvent-dewaxed

  61789-86-4      <5       calcium petroleum sulfonate

  111-76-2        1-3      ethylene glycol monobutyl ether

  Not Available    1       fragrance
- Check the SDS info using physical/chemical testing
  If you have the gear available :
  Density
  Distillation
  FTIR
  GC (GC-MS if you have it)
  AAS/ICP - metals (ICP multielement would be best)
  CHOSNP analysis for hetero atoms
- Rebuild the product from data. Check to see if it performs the same.
- Improve on the product (believe me - WD-40 is NOT the be all and end all of penetrating oils - technology has improved since its formulation).

Comment: No one is asking for the precations, read the question carefully

Comment: What are "precations"? The questioner asked why the product's formulation couldn't be determined by spectroscopic/chemical means. Trivial answer is - it can (it has been). The process is trivial if you have the right equipment and background.I included a schema to follow to derive the formulation - it completes the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A fundamental problem in analytical chemistry is that we never analyze a complete unknown mixture simply because of time and money constraints. Finding each and every component of a complex unknown mixture is quite impossible. NMR is good for pure compounds only, mass spectrometer is "blind" to several analytes because they do not ionize very well. It is unable to distinguish the masses of isomers. You may ask what can't we make synthetic gasoline? The reason is that it literally contains thousand and thousands of compounds and people are even discovering more by using million dollar Fourier transform ion cyclotron resonance mass spectrometers. So back to the question, is it worth analyzing *a completely unknown* mixture?

Comment: Having said that, WD-40 is rather far from being completely unknown.

Comment: No idea if it's worth it (It's big business AFAIK). How much do you think it would cost to analyze it?

Comment: Several thousand dollars at the minimum. See here, someone attempted gas chromatography https://www.wired.com/2009/04/st-whatsinside-6/

Comment: WD-40's annual revenue is \$381M and income is \$76M (they have other products too though)

Comment: Hmm, NMR can handle mixtures even if it does have a somewhat high detection limit and all those overlapping alkanes might prove challenging (if not impossible) to disentangle. Not push-button technology exactly. You can also use hyphenated techniques (GC-NMR) in parallel with GC-MS which would be a step up from the quick analysis in the linked wired article.

Comment: @BuckThorn, I am sure coupling GC with NMR must be a very expensive set up. It is amazing that it is possible.  The caveat is that one must use a preparative GC.

Comment: @M.Farooq You can run it in-line with special microvolume probes. NMR probe coil sensitivity increases with smaller size which makes up for the decreased mass of sample. The technique is pretty mature but I don't know about expense, certainly the NMR instrument will be the most expensive part. See eg https://www.bruker.com/products/mr/nmr/probes/probes/flow-nmr-probes.html

Comment: We can make synthetic gasoline - in fact pretty much all gasoline from a modern refinery is "synthetic". The molecules expressed in the final product don't start in the original crude - alkylation, isomer rebuilding, cracking, distillation all modify the product profile - we do it all the time. An d that doesn't even mention things like the "gasohol" conversion process (ExxonMobil). Balancing the final product is the job of a fuels chemist / technologist - correct IBP/FBP, Octane #, evaporation profile, benzine content, RON/MON, etc. We literally do this all the time.

Comment: Bruce Heath, My point is that gasoline whether synthetic or natural is very hard to analyze. No one can do a total and complete analysis (= identifying each molecule and isomer therein) of such complex mixtures without spending years or dedicated service.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree - gasoline is basically just a series of hydrocarbons, occasionally with some oxygenates or additives. GC-MS makes both qualitative and quantitative evaluation of the mixture not only possible but relatively trivial. Sure, it's a $1MM dollar piece of equipment, but it's also a relatively common piece of equipment in any large commercial analytical laboratory. Couple that to a reasonable background in petroleum chemical manufacturing and you'll get the "formulation" of gasoline +/- a few %. Nobody is going to "build" gasoline from discrete components - but analysis is trivial,

Comment: I'm reminded of a formulation I was asked to produce about 40 years ago by someone who had taken a sample of an anti-corrosive spray to a University for evaluation. The chemists at the uni had GC/MSd the product and done ICP to determine metals present - the customer ended up with a 45 page list of "ingredients" and asked me to reproduce the product - I looked at it and the analysis and said - "Bitumen  + wax+ barium sulphonate + solvent". "But what about all these other bits" - :"That's the bitumen - that's the wax - that's the solvent" - "pure" chemists just don't "get" real world products